# WPF VSTS App Hanging on VS Credential Prompt

Tags: c#, wpf, azure-devops

I'm trying to write an application that uses the Visual Studio Team Service (VSTS) API to display items from Visual Studio Online.

I have the following code that works perfectly in a Console application:

```
var connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(collectionUri), new VssClientCredentials());
using (var witClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>())
{
    var wiql = new Wiql {
        Query = "SELECT [System.Id] FROM WorkItems WHERE State = 'New'"
    };
    var workItems = await witClient.QueryByWiqlAsync(wiql);
}
```

In a Console app, I receive a Visual Studio prompt to enter credentials, and everything works great. However, when I run the same code from WPF, I don't get the prompt, and the application just seems to hang.

I had this working in my WPF app for a brief moment after allowing it to run asynchronously from a button click event. Then I made some more changes, and--hours later--I just haven't been able to get it. I <kbd>CTRL+Z</kbd>'d my way back to the point where it was working and still--nothing. I suspect this has something to do with thread management, and I've tried everything I can think of with using `Dispatcher.Invoke` and running in `Window_Loaded` or hooking it up to a button.

I'm completely stumped.

I'm using the following NuGet package:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient
```

Comment: You need to start a new thread to execute, I updated my answer you can check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to start another thread to execute that (e.g. System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run).

For example:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var workitem = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => GetItems(123)).Result;

        }
 public WorkItem GetItems(int itemId)
        {
            var myCredentials = new VssClientCredentials();
            var vstsConnection = new VssConnection(new Uri(@"https://XXX.visualstudio.com/"), myCredentials);
            var vstsClient = vstsConnection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
            var workItem = vstsClient.GetWorkItemAsync(itemId).Result;

            return workItem;
        }
```

On the other hand, you can specify account in your code directly (could be let user to provide account by using a custom login window).

```
var u = new Uri("XXX");
VssCredentials c = new VssCredentials(new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.WindowsCredential(new NetworkCredential("[user name]", "[password]")));
var connection = new VssConnection(u, c);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
TfsClientCredentials tcc = new TfsClientCredentials();
                tcc.AllowInteractive = true;
                TfsTeamProjectCollection  ttpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("https://xjsdal.visualstudio.com"), tcc);
                using (var witClient = ttpc.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>())
                {
                    var wiql = new Wiql
                    {
                        Query = "SELECT [System.Id] FROM WorkItems WHERE State = 'New'"
                    };
                    var workItems = await witClient.QueryByWiqlAsync(wiql);
                }
```