# How to handle VSTS credentials in a VSIX extension

Tags: c#, azure-devops, vsix

I have a Visual Studio extension that we use internally for a project and one of the things it needs to be able to do is post tickets to VSTS. Previously we were using onsite TFS and making a connection to post tickets was as simple as:

```
var vssCreds = new VssCredentials(true);    
projectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(url, vssCreds);
workItems = projectCollection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
project = workItems.Projects["My Project"];
defaultType = project.WorkItemTypes["Bug"];

//...
var newItem = new WorkItem(defaultType)
{
    Title = title
};
newItem.Fields["Assigned To"].Value = assignTo;
newItem.Fields["Repro Steps"].Value = repoSteps;
var validationResult = newItem.Validate();
newItem.Save();
```

And this worked fine. But after upgrading to VSTS I'm having a hard time getting the credentials part to work. I changed this line:

```
projectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(url, vssCreds);
```

To this:

```
projectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(url, new VssClientCredentials());
```

And this worked fine for me. But when I share it with other people on my team it didn't work at first and then started working a little later. I am guessing that interacting with VSTS caused their credentials to be loaded so that it then worked. But I have at least one person who just seems to be completely unable to make it work.

So what's the correct way to get it to use the VSTS credentials (that should already exist in VS)?

I see this overload for `VssClientCredentials` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn228355(v=vs.120).aspx):

```
public VssClientCredentials(
    IVssCredentialPrompt credentialPrompt
)
```

Which I suspect might be useful, but I can't seem to find out if there's a built in implementation of `IVssCredentialPrompt` somewhere or, if not, how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the related key from 
`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSCommon\14.0\ClientServices\TokenStorage\VisualStudio\VssApp`, then authentication again.

You also can specify other Kind (vssApp by default) and Namespace (VisualStudio by default) by using this code:

```
var c = new VssClientCredentials();
c.Storage = new VssClientCredentialStorage(storageKind: "VssApp2", storageNamespace: "VisualStudio");
projectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(url, c);
```

Comment: _You also can specify other Kind (vssApp by default) and Namespace_, okay. But is that something I want to do? Is it explained somewhere?

Comment: @MattBurland If you login through Visual Studio, it will store the credentical in `...\VisualStudio\VssApp`, to specify the Kind or Namespace if you don't want to use that credential.

Comment: So this still isn't working for me. I have one person who deleted the key and it made no difference. Another told me they couldn't find the key in the first place.

Comment: @MattBurland What's the version of Visual Studio? What's error message?

Comment: It's `TF30063: You are not authorized to access xxxx.visualstudio.com\xxxx. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized`. It's always that error, but they are logged in in VS and can, for example, check files in and out. They are using VS 2017 community, v 15.5.6

Comment: Do you mean it isn't working even through specify different Kind? Does it prompt the login window?

Comment: It doesn't prompt ever. Weirdly I created a console app for something different and that did show a prompt. Specifying a different kind makes it not even work for me

Comment: What're packages installed on that project? What's the version?

Comment: I installed the `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient` package from NuGet. Version 15.112.1

Comment: So I stumbled across this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40256731/1250301 (which is from you) and this seems to be the answer. If I run the line that attempts to get the project collection in it's own thread it works for reasons that are completely unclear. It will actually prompt for creds if it doesn't have them.

Comment: @MattBurland Do you mean it works fine in another thread? Do not clear about "get the project collection in it's own thread it works", what's the complete code?

Answer (score 0):

For reasons that are entirely unclear and from this answer to an entirely different question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40256731/1250301

It seems that spawning a new thread causes a login prompt to appear if needed and fix all the problems. So if I do this:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    var url = new Uri(_tfsUrl);
    var cred = new VssClientCredentials();
    projectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(url, cred);
    workItems = projectCollection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
}).Wait();

project = workItems.Projects["Job Posting Data"];
defaultType = project.WorkItemTypes["Bug"];
taskType = project.WorkItemTypes["Task"];
```

Then it works. I have no idea why it works, or why this is necessary (at first I thought maybe it was a problem with *not* being in the UI thread so I'd tried `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke` which did not work) but it seems to have fixed the problem.